# Why do I not see network tab requests in the browser when using NextJS SSR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am working on a React application that was built using SSR for SEO purposes. How does SSR with NextJS work? The requests must be being made from somewhere; if not the browser, then where? Thank you!

Comment: Which tab are you checking for the requests? It would show up in the Network tab, but it would be a precompiled html, so it'll most likely show in the docs tab.

Comment: I have "All" selected on the Network tab

Comment: You should see a network call with the type of `document`. If not, paste an image of your network tab here and maybe we can figure it out further.

Answer (score 8):

You are most probably using `getInitialProps` for data fetching.

If so, you don't see the requests in your network tab on first page load because they are done on the server side.
While if you navigate somewhere from this page after its initial load and then go back to the page needed, you'll see your requets in network tab. That is because the following data-fetching is done by NextJS on the client-side (from your browser).

For more info you can refer to the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

> getInitialProps is used to asynchronously fetch some data, which then
> populates props.
>
> For the initial page load, getInitialProps will run on the server
> only. getInitialProps will then run on the client when navigating to a
> different route via the next/link component or by using next/router.
> However, if getInitialProps is used in a custom _app.js, and the page
> being navigated to implements getServerSideProps, then getInitialProps
> will run on the server.